# What happens if two networks have the same SSID and password?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wifi-configuration, ssid, mifi

Related to this question: [What happens if 2 wifi networks (run by different people) have the same SSID?](https://superuser.com/questions/955671/what-happens-if-2-wifi-networks-run-by-different-people-have-the-same-ssid)

*BUT* in my case both WiFi have the *same* password.

I have two cases to consider:

1. If they are broadcasting in the same location, what will happen?
2. If they are in different locations, will devices which know about WiFi A automatically connect to WiFi B?

I'm setting up a WiFi using a MiFi dongle for use on vacation and wondered if I set it up the same SSID/password as my home Wifi, if I can save everyone having to add a new Wifi to all their devices... which these days is quite a large number!

Is SSID/password all that identifies a WiFi network to my PC or would different security settings mean it is not seen as the 'same' network?

Answer (score 12):

Two identically named SSIDs with the same password will allow your device to connect to either, without having to add any extra networks on your devices.

If both routers are broadcasting from the same location, the expected behaviour will vary depending on device. For example, some devices will connect to whichever router has the stronger signal, others will just connect to the first router they "see".

Comment: Are SSID names case-sensitive?

Comment: @Mr.Boy Yes, at least my android phone saw 2 different WiFi when only one letter was in different case.

Comment: does it mean that I can create a fake spot with the same ssid and receive a password from devices that this is the original access point?

Comment: @stokito The client (nor the access point) never send the password; see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/517677) ([and Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=IEEE_802.11i-2004&oldid=892301691#Four-way_handshake)).

Comment: @Sergey Ponomarev You can't receive a password in the way that you're probably thinking. First of all it is salted with the SSID name (the SSID is quietly added to the password after you type it in), and second it is encrypted so you can never figure out the original password any more easily than you can if you just monitored a client connecting to a WPA passworded access point.

Answer (score 5):

The [other answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1090802/598796) is technically correct on "it will **allow your device to connect to either** (if both of them are broadcasting from the same location)", but there is a subtle detail here and the actual result is probably not what you hope 2 same SSID would do in the first place. The actual outcome is: **Your devices do not seem to be able to roam between the 2 SSID networks**!

Data source: my own experience with some devices from named brands.

My setup:

1. I originally also setup 2 WiFi routers (one is actually creating a downstream sub-network within another). Both have identical SSID+password (and same 2.4GHz frequency, for that matter), at upstairs and downstairs in my house, in hoping that they would be seen as same network, thus allowing my devices to freely roam from one to another, whenever they see fit (hopefully based on signal strength).
2. Such setup seemed to work in the way I expected, in a sense that all my phones, tablets and computers show only one available WiFi network, rather than two with same names. My devices can connect to that network, and work just fine.
3. But, in hindsight, my devices displaying only one SSID network might just mean they silently hide the other one with the same SSID; it does not necessarily mean these devices can roam between both. In everyday usage, you just won't know. A device might just be sticking with one WiFi network all the time.
4. How/when did I realize things weren't right? Recently I happened to disable my downstairs router, and then I found out a certain set of my devices became offline. In their network setting menu, there is still one seemingly same WiFi network as a "remembered network" meaning the device does have the password, but tapping the "Connect" button would always fail. Realizing what was happening, I can experimentally re-enable my downstairs router and disable the upstairs router, now my previously unable-to-connect devices can work, but the another set of devices would become offline.

**The conclusion: Setting up 2 WiFi networks with same SSID+password is not the "poor man's mesh WiFi" that I hope it would be.**

Comment: One issue, in point 1 might be the "and same 2.4GHz frequency". It might depend where everything is located, but definitely the same freq will create a lot of noise. So I would use 2 different and separated bands.

Comment: @mariotti, how is the noise of 2.4GHz (or the presumable nonexistence of noise in 5GHz) relevant in this topic? We are not talking about signal strength; we are talking about whether clients can roam between 2 same-name WiFi networks.

Comment: Beh, 2 points, close enough, with same name and frequency. Might get noise (or signal). Indeed, I might not have answered  the question.

Comment: The DD-WRT [documentation](https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_access_point#Roaming_access) says that this _should_ work. Maybe you had the same password but different security types? e.g. one WPA, one WPA2?

Comment: @forresthopkinsa, thanks for sharing that DD-WRT [Roaming access](https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_access_point#Roaming_access). It sounds undecisive. They said it *should* work, and they also said "... The clients control when to switch in between APs. Most clients will switch when...". BTW, I just double checked my setup. My 2 routers both use same WPA2-PSK, AES encryption, same passphrase. FWIW, their LAN is also seemingly same 192.168.1.1/8, but they are probably considered 2 different subnets. But different IP networks shouldn't affect WiFi routing, or should they?

Comment: I just tried this with my own network and it worked, though I'm not using two different subnets so YMMV. Note: my Macbook was _extremely_ reluctant to roam between access points. As long as there was any sign of the signal it originally connected to, it wouldn't switch to a stronger one. Only when the initial network was absolutely undetectable would it finally roam to the other AP. AFAICT this is a known issue with MacOS.

Comment: @forresthopkinsa I've been bitten by this "should work" thing many times, and it is simply not reliable.  Many ioT devices for example will **not** find an SSID with the same credentials (name,key etc.) even if the MAC addres of the AP is spoofed to be the same, devices are still unable to connect.    It's damned annoying when you have an installation where the AP fails and needs replacing, and there's a ton of _smart_ devices that need manual reconfig. (Note: many devices will just connect to the other wifi, esp laptops, smart phones.  YMMV, just be aware it's a thing.)

Comment: @ocodo if the BSSID is the same, how can they distinguish between the APs? very weird

Comment: I'd guess it's MAC address, but honestly no idea. If I hadn't seen this happen at multiple sites, I wouldn't belive it happens. (Since it's not the expected behaviour and statistically it's relatively rare, and client device specific)

Answer (score 0):

I know that an iPhone 12 will allow an identically named network (with or without security) to connect and replace  an operating network if the device being managed is configured to allow it to connect. Hidden  or not, the newcomer can displace the running network if appropriately configured. I can supply screen shots of two identically  named networks waiting to commect to my wifi. Usually the intruder is hidden (not broadcasting  its ssid), because thats how wifi hacks begin. The intruder doesnt need the legit password, by the way.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).